# Install fail "Parted can't resize partitions managed by window dynamic Disk"

Tags: window, resize, partitioning

How to solve the problem? (The existing system is Windows 7, 64-bit.)

Comment: @Braiam Doesn't Ubiquity use `parted` behind the scenes for partitioning? It makes sense that this message would occur during installation of Ubuntu, even without the OP having manually invoked `parted` or `gparted`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Windows convert the disk back to a basic disk ( in the disk utility ).

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts offical policy is a full backup, erase dynamic partitions and create new basic partitions. There is no undo.
Dynamic volume is a Microsoft proprietary format developed together with Veritas (now acquired by Symantec) for logical volumes.
You may be use a third-party tool, such as Partition Wizard MiniTool or EASEUS to convert a convert a dynamic disk to a basic disk without having to delete or format them.

I've never used any of these and so I can't be sure they will work.Be sure to have good backups as any major partition change has risks.
Dynamic also on gpt as LDM

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html